# SQL Server triggers aren't working with Linq to SQL on ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, linq-to-sql

My work colleague is making the `ASP.NET Web Forms` application collecting data. I'm administrating `SQL Server` database of it. Based on databse he makes objects to Web Forms using `Linq to SQL`. He wanted me to make recodrds in Osoby to change `dataDodania` with date of generation the object and `dataModyfikacji` with date of last update. Having experience in PL/SQL I made simple triggers for this. The problem is that triggers work when I run SQL statements in `SQL Server Management Studio 2008` nicely, but when used in application - they are omitted, not making changes needed. Here is triggers SQL code:

```
CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[DodanieOsoby]
   ON  [dbo].[Osoby]
   INSTEAD OF INSERT
AS 
BEGIN
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
        INSERT INTO Osoby(dataDodania, dataModyfikacji, loginId, rola, imie, imieDrugie, nazwisko, plec, wiek,pESEL,wyksztalcenie,opieka,ulica, nrDom, nrLokal, miejscowosc, obszar, kodPoczty, telefonKontakt, telefonStacjo, email, zatrudnienie, stanowisko, przedsiebiorstwo)
        SELECT GETDATE(), GETDATE(), loginId, rola, imie, imieDrugie, nazwisko, plec, wiek, pESEL, wyksztalcenie,opieka,ulica, nrDom, nrLokal, miejscowosc, obszar, kodPoczty, telefonKontakt, telefonStacjo, email, zatrudnienie, stanowisko, przedsiebiorstwo
        FROM inserted 
END
```

And for UPDATE of `Osoby`...

```
CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[AktualizacjaOsoby]
   ON  [dbo].[Osoby]
   AFTER UPDATE
AS 
BEGIN
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
        UPDATE Osoby
        SET dataModyfikacji = GETDATE()
        WHERE id in 
        (SELECT DISTINCT id from Inserted)
END
```

Answer (score 0):

Possible this be helpful for you (if dbo.Osoby is view) -

```
ALTER TRIGGER dbo.trg_IOIU_vw_WorkOut

   ON dbo.vw_WorkOut
   INSTEAD OF INSERT, UPDATE

AS BEGIN

    SET NOCOUNT ON
    SET XACT_ABORT ON

    DECLARE
          @WorkOutID BIGINT
        , @DateOut DATETIME
        , @EmployeeID INT

    DECLARE workout CURSOR LOCAL READ_ONLY FAST_FORWARD FOR
        SELECT
              WorkOutID
            , DateOut
            , EmployeeID
        FROM INSERTED

    OPEN workout

    FETCH NEXT FROM workout INTO
          @WorkOutID
        , @DateOut
        , @EmployeeID

    WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0 BEGIN

        IF NOT EXISTS(
            SELECT 1 
            FROM dbo.WorkOut 
            WHERE WorkOutID = @WorkOutID
        )
        BEGIN

            INSERT INTO dbo.WorkOut
            (
                  EmployeeID
                , DateOut
            )
            SELECT
                  @EmployeeID
                , @DateOut

            SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY() -- if you use LINQ need return new ID to client

        END
        ELSE BEGIN

            UPDATE dbo.WorkOut
            SET 
                  EmployeeID = @EmployeeID
                , DateOut = @DateOut
            WHERE WorkOutID = @WorkOutID

        END

        FETCH NEXT FROM workout INTO
              @WorkOutID
            , @DateOut
            , @EmployeeID

    END

    CLOSE workout
    DEALLOCATE workout

END
```

Comment: For now I used `default ( GETDATE() )` Constraint for `dataDodania`. Still use trigger for `UPDATE` but don't know with what to change it...